# What's the difference between "block" and "loop" in WebAssembly spec?

Tags: webassembly

As titled, the spec says that "loop" is

> a block with a label at the beginning which may be used to form loops.

and for "block":

> the beginning of a block construct, a sequence of instructions with a label at the end.

But with the help of "***br***" (used for switching branch to a labeled block), I can form the same control structure even with "block", right?. So, what's the difference between these two instructions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `br` to a block label jumps to the *end* of the contained instruction sequence -- it behaves like a `break` statement in C.

A `br` to a loop label jumps to the *start* of the contained instruction sequence -- it behaves like a `continue` statement in C.

The former enables a *forward* jump, the latter a *backwards* jump. Neither can express the other.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, the "br" and "br_if" instructions have one immediate operand stands for "relative_depth", what's the usage of this immediate?

Comment: It denotes the jump target, counting blocks inside out.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't block has the label at end as it sayed block has the label at the end

```
LOOP START
label:
SOME CODE
IF condtion BR label:
EVEN MORE CODE
LOOP END
```

Will execute SOME CODE once. Than repeats SOME CODE until condition is not true. And than execute EVEN MORE CODE

```
BLOCK START
SOME CODE
IF condition BR label:
EVEN MORE CODE
label:
BLOCK END
```

Will execute SOME CODE only once. And than EVEN MORE CODE might be execute when contdtion is not true.